# What exactly happens when you connect two voltage sources in parallel? Why isn't it the same case when they are connected in series?

Tags: voltage, current

I have read that when two voltage sources of different magnitudes are connected in parallel (same polarities connected together,) a high current flows from voltage source of high magnitude to source of low magnitude since the internal resistance of a voltage source is zero and thus the voltage source is damaged. I don't understand how the lower voltage source can accept high current into it if it itself is trying to push out electrons.

Answer (score 2):

> *What exactly happens when you connect two voltage sources in parallel?*

Think of a 12 volt source connected to a 10 volt source. Can you see that is just the same as a 2 volt source connected to a 0 volt source. And, can you also see that a 0 volt source is in fact a short-circuit.

> *Why isn't it the same case when they are connected in series?*

- When you connect them in series you are **not** making a circuit loop that allows current to flow.
- When you connect them in parallel you **are** making a circuit loop that allows rather a lot of current to flow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be to think it pushes out electrons. It does not push out electrons. Maybe better to think in current, and the higher voltage source providing infinite amount of current and lower voltage source sinking infinite amount of current, because you can't have a node between two voltages with zero resistance so it will be undefined.

Think of two car batteries, one empty and one full, connected in parallel. Full battery may charge the empty battery with tens of amperes. And because they have real resistance, the copper wire between 12V and 10V battery might be at 11V.

Now, having two ideal voltage sources in series is just one ideal voltage source with voltage that is the sum of the two ideal sources.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing reality and the way we model it. The circuit diagrams we use as models are imperfect. The connections between components have some resistance and voltage sources are usually more complicated, one of the complications being source resistance. So what? The models are good enough for  our analyses. If any of the complexities is important we can add to the model. As for pushing electrons, battery charging is a simple example of the normal pushor becoming a pushee. (Just coined those terms)